# File as a sub-field on Advanced Custom Fields (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields for Wordpress and I've got a field set as "Group" and one of the subfields inside "Group" is a file (which is mp4 video). Can anyone provide the code for displaying this video file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily loop through your group with the `have_rows()` method. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/#template-usage

```
<?php
if( have_rows('group_name') ):
    while( have_rows('group_name') ): the_row(); 
        // Get your video file field
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Inside the loop you will grab the subfield with the `get_sub_field()` method.

The URL from this video file you can use inside the video and source tag.
**Make sure the ACF field returns a URL!**

```
<video controls>
    <source src="<?= $subfield_url; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video element.
</video>
```

If it's not inside a loop/repeater you can easily grab the group field.

```
<?php
$group_name = get_field('group_name');
$group_name['video_acf_name']['url'];
```

Comment: Thank you, @Tygo. But my file is actually a video (not an audio file) and there's no link to it - again, the actual file has been uploaded onto its respective fields within Advanced Custom Fields. Being so, my question was - how to grab a file (which is a video) sub field? Thanks!

Comment: @scubaM this works the same for video files. You just change audio inside the array to video and change the html to video too. I updated the answer